# Configure Amazon SES on PHPbb3

Tags: amazon-web-services, phpbb, phpbb3

I'm actually looking for how to use Amazon SES on phpbb3. I tried to use the SMTP of ses but this didn't work. Is there another way to do this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EDIT: I figured it out.

I'm using phpBB3 3.0.10

SMTP: tls://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com  (you have to add that tls:// prefix!)

Port: 465

Authentication method for SMTP: PLAIN

SMTP username/password: Use the one you configured in Amazon IAM.

For example, my username is AKIAJKVKV2TENFEUP6WA and password is even more complex.

Based on initial findings, Amazon SMS is pretty snappy. Gets delivered within a few seconds.

-Josh

Comment: Thanks - it was the tls:// prefix I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to make sure you have first verified the Reply to and From email addresses in Amazon SES using the Verify Senders that are shown under E-Mail settings in the Administration Control Panel, otherwise the emails won't go out.

Comment: You can also just verify the domain name of those Reply To/Email addresses, without having to verify the email addresses themselves. "... you must verify each email address (or the domain of the email address) that you will use as a "From", "Source", "Sender", or "Return-Path" address for your messages. " http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html